# Given $16t^2 +h = 64$ question asks to find $\delta h$ between t= 1 to 1.1, why is the answer -3.36? instead of 3.36?

Tags: calculus, limits

$16t^2 +h = 64$

$h = 64-16t^2$

Sub t = 1: $h = 64-16(1)^2 = 48$

Sub t = 1.1: $h = 64-16(1)^2 = 44.64$

Interval or $\Delta$h: 48-44.64=3.36

Shown also on this graph, it seems clear to me that the interval between 1 to 1.1 is = 3.36:
[image]

Why does the answer in this question pick -3.36 as the answer?

[image]

Comment: You should check what definition of $\Delta$ they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find $\delta h$ from $t=1$ to $t=1.1$. Here, $\delta t = 1.1-1 =+0.1$. So just like we find slope at a point, what we need to find here is $$\delta h = h(x=1.1) - h(x=1) = 44.64-48 = -3.36, \text{ where } \delta t=+0.1$$

Comment: I'm sorry which is the independent(& dependent) variable in this case and what makes it independent/dependent..?

So when they say "change in", we'll need to take the later variable - the original variable..?

Comment: @nvs0000 To be very concise, if the question asked "from the interval t=1.1 to t=1" in the last line your answer would be correct.

Comment: The interval (t=1 to t=1.1) and (t=1.1 to t=1) is not the same

Comment: So we need to take "number to" -  "number from" to get the interval value..?

Comment: @nvs0000 Yes, correct